# HP ALM - How to get the exact Test Set from FindTestSets method?

Tags: vba, alm

I am trying to get the Test Set.

Now when I write

```
FindTestSets("ABC")
```

It gives me a number of Test Sets with name ABC, like

```
ABC
ABC 1
ABC 2
etc.
```

I want only ABC Test Set, no other similar named Test Sets, so I tried this:

```
FindTestSets("ABC", True)
```

Referred from [here](http://alm-help.saas.hp.com/en/12.50/api_refs/ota/webframe.html)

But again it does not match the exact case, it still gives me a number of similar name Test Sets.

Please suggest how can I get the exact name Test Set.

thanks.

I am using HP ALM 11.50

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try below (code is in F# but the logic and the class name is similar):

```
let testSetFactory = connection.TestSetFactory :?> TestSetFactory
let filter = testSetFactory.Filter :?> TDFilter
filter.["CY_CYCLE"] <- "ABC"
let result = testSetFactory.NewList(filter.Text)
printfn "%d" result.Count
for test in result do
    test :?> TestSet
    |> fun t -> printfn "%s" t.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

The Lib says:

> Function **FindTestSets**(Pattern As String, [MatchCase As Boolean = False], Filter As String]) As List
>
> Member of TDAPIOLELib.ITestSetFolder
>
> Gets the list of test sets contained in the folder that match the specified pattern."

You try to search for a TestSet but use a function that searches a folder.

If you only want to search for one specific TestSet you can also search for it's ID. The ID should be unique. I do not know if you want to search for the string though.

Either filter like Albert said (for ID or Name) or try using the Name function of the TestSet Class. If you have the factory with all TestSets it should not be a problem to check for the correct Name.